# Rails show specific results from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following models

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :client
   has_and_belongs_to_many :user_groups

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
   has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
end

class UserGroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Now I want to display for one user to which user groups he belongs to.

I tried this:

```
@usergroups = UserGroup.joins(:users).where('user_groups.client_id IN (?)', [@current_client.id, session[:user_id]]).group('name').order('name')
```

But the result is anything, but not that what I expected. ...

The User Group Users looks like this:
[image]

I Want A list with all user_Groups for one User_ID how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
User.find(user_id).try(:user_groups)
```

or if you have the User object available (an it's not null):

```
user.user_groups
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this: @usergroups = `User.find(session[:user_id]).user_groups` --> Result is empty

Comment: Just to double check: whats the value of `session[:user_id]`?
Tip: If you are using devise gem, try using `current_user`.

Comment: I've checked already the session[:user_ID] is the correct ID that works. I tink in user.find ... Is a Problem?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. If `session[:user_id]` is correct, using `User.find(session[:user_id]).try(:user_groups)` should work. If it's not, go to `rails console` and check it out using the id value itself instead of `session[:user_id]`.

Comment: yeah but the result of this "query"? is not that what I want ... result is empty ....